# How to click on hidden button via VBA Selenium Chrome?

Tags: vba, selenium

I am trying to click on a button on a website using VBA Selenium via Chrome.

When I use VBA code to click the button, ElementNotVisibleError pops up:
[image]

VBA code:

```vb
Set CD = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
CD.Start
CD.Get Url

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
CD.FindElementByCss(".inline_cancel").Click
```

When I move the mouse to the place where button is, the button appears and HTML code style display changes to block and before it was none.

When set to "none" VBA cannot find the element.
[image: None]

When set to "block" VBA can detect the element.
[image: block]

HTML code:

```
<span class="edit-hover" style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="field_root_name" id="order_header_change_attachments_attributes__field_name" value="order_header_change[attachments_attributes][]" class="field_root_name"><input type="hidden" value="365995938" name="order_header_change[attachments_attributes][365995938][id]" id="order_header_change_attachments_attributes_365995938_id"><input value="false" class="delete-field" type="hidden" name="order_header_change[attachments_attributes][365995938][_delete]" id="order_header_change_attachments_attributes_365995938__delete"><span class="intent-field"><span class="attachment-intent-checkbox"><input name="order_header_change[attachments_attributes][365995938][intent]" type="hidden" value="Internal"><input class="intent_checkbox_field" id="attachment_365995938_intent" type="checkbox" value="Supplier" name="order_header_change[attachments_attributes][365995938][intent]">→&nbsp;<label for="attachment_365995938_intent">Supplier</label></span></span><a aria-label="Delete Attachment" class="inline_cancel" href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" tabindex="0">&nbsp;</a></span>
```

Comment: seems like you want to hover first, then find/click the element. (with a proper webdriverwait and expected condition of to be clickable)

Comment: It looks like you need Actions for this. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/

Just move the mouse and then click. This can't be done with just the click function.

Comment: I would like to run it background, so without visible chrome. do you think it is still possible to click that button?

Answer (score 0):

You saw it right. Clearly the desired element:

```
<a aria-label="Delete Attachment" class="inline_cancel" href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" tabindex="0">&nbsp;</a>
```

have the ***ancestor*** `<span>` with attribute **`style="display: none;"`**

```
<span class="edit-hover" style="display: none;">
```

which implies the element is ***hidden*** i.e. either not ***visible*** or not ***enabled***.

To click on the element you have make the desired element *clickable* by taking some actions on some other element first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. do you have any ideas how I could make it clickable, please? how I could write it in VBA so macro click on the hidden element?

Comment: Sounds to be a different question all together.  Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.